# Find N from $2^N - 1= R$

Tags: number-theory, limits

I have the following formula, which gives the range of bits when provided a number of bits which is $N$:

$$2^N-1=R$$

How would we transform the equation to be like:

$$N = \ldots$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you heard of logarithms?
$$2^N - 1 = R \implies 2^N = R+1 \implies N = \log_2(R+1). $$

Comment: It is not necessary to give a sarcastic comment before answering.

Comment: It's not necessarily sarcastic. Definitely if OP has never heard of logarithms, then the solution won't make much sense.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It was not at all meant to be sarcastic. My answer required the knowledge of logarithms and hence I wanted to make sure of that first. Otherwise the answer wouldn't be understandable.

Answer (score 5):

$$2^N=R+1$$
$$N=\log_{2}(R+1)$$

Answer (score 5):

Set $$R=2^{N}-1$$

Then
$$1+R=2^N \qquad (\text{add $1$ to both sides})$$
hence
$$\log_2\left(1+R\right)=N\qquad (\text{take $\log$ to base $2$ of both sides})$$